# Java: setting a objects variable in outside function

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player Anfallare = new Player("A");
        Player Forsvarare = new Player("F");
        MotVarandra(Anfallare.getDice(1), Forsvarare.getDice(1));
    (...)
   }
```

Is what I have in main function, now I made a own function,

```
public static void MotVarandra(int a, int f){
    if(f >= a){
        Anfallare.armees-=1;
    }else{
        Forsvarare.armees-=1;
    }
}
```

which should set the object's variable to -=1.. But this doesn't work because the function doesnt know that Anfallare and Forsvarare is an object..

What can i do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the `Player`s as class fields, instead of inside the main method.

For a gentle introduction to Java, I suggest you to start reading here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Also, there are great book suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far . Some of those books are great to begin learning.

---

**Example here:**

```
public class Game {
  private static Player Anfallare, Forsvarare; //  <-- you define them here, so they are available to any method in the class

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Anfallare = new Player("A");  //  <-- it is already defined as a Player, so now you only need to instantiate it
    Forsvarare = new Player("F");
    MotVarandra(Anfallare.getDice(1), Forsvarare.getDice(1));
    // ...
  }
  public static void MotVarandra(int a, int f){
    if(f >= a){
        Anfallare.armees-=1; //  <-- it is already defined and instantiated
    }else{
        Forsvarare.armees-=1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im learning Java in school and Im trying to make a own little project game but thanks for links although could you maybe specify another link more detail about how to define the players as class fields instead inside in main?

Comment: @Karem from the oracle link, follow "Language Basics" and "Classes and Objects". It will be much more helpful than just an example. Anyway, I added the example so you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: BTW, If you need to access the players form *outside* the class, you need to change `private` to `public` or create a set of "getters" and "setters" as Fredrik says.

Comment: thank you, learned something new today! I am receiving non-static method cannot be referenced from a static content on my public static void functions. I tried to change it to public void, but then my Motvandra() in the main are saying the same, because main is public static void. What do i do? Appreciate your patience..

Comment: @Karem I was not really thinking about the main method, do I forgot to add the static modifier to the variable. In a real program, you would create a hierarchy of objects and instantiate each player as instance fields instead of class fields. See the discussion about it here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 2):

While Aleadam's solution is by far the best answer, another thing you could do to specifically resolve this issue is change the arguments of the function:

```
public static void MotVarandra(Player a, Player f){
    if(f.getDice(1) >= a.getDice(1)){
        f.armees-=1;
    }else{
        a.armees-=1;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, your optimal solution just depends on what your program is doing. Chances are, this is just another way of looking at it.

As a side note, be sure to use descriptive naming techniques, a and f are somewhat hard coded, and only make sense if you use only those variable names for your Players. It's best to not potentially limit your code.