# Java: do while wont while

Tags: java

```
    Anfallare.armees = 10;
    Forsvarare.armees = 10;
 do{
    Anfallare.slaTarningar();
    Forsvarare.slaTarningar();

    Anfallare.visaTarningar();
    Forsvarare.visaTarningar();

    MotVarandra(Anfallare, Forsvarare);

    status(Anfallare, Forsvarare);

    }while(Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0);
```

is what I have, I tried also a

```
 System.out.println(Anfallare.armees + " :: " + Forsvarare.armees);
```

after this do while and it is 9 and 10, neither of them are 0.

Why does it run this once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0)
```

Means continue only if `Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0`.  In your example, neither is 0 so it will not loop.

```
while(Anfallare.armees != 0 && Forsvarare.armees != 0)
```

Means, stop looping if either are zero (`Anfallare.armees != 0 && Forsvarare.armees != 0`)

You may actually be wanting:

```
while (Anfallare.armees != 0 || Forsvarare.armees != 0)
```

means, stop looping if both are 0

Answer (score 7):

Because, as you point out, after the first run, Anfallare.armees is 9, which does not equal 0, and Forsvarare.armees is 10, which is not equal to 0.

Perhaps you meant

```
while(Anfallare.armees != 0 && Forsvarare.armees != 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do

```
while(Anfallare.armees != 0 || Forsvarare.armees != 0);
```

To make it loop until both of those variables are 0

Answer (score 2):

Because you start as `do{}`, which forces to execute at least once the code, and then you have while `x==0`, which is not true. Since it is not true, the loop ends.

As you see in the other answers, you may need to check for `x != 0` (not equal to), or even better `x>0` (in the event x could take a negative number)

Take some time to read the Oracle's Java tutorials I linked in [the other answer to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128198/java-setting-a-objects-variable-in-outside-function/6128222#6128222). It explains the loop logic very well.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your `do-while` loop body is executed once, but you think it shouldn't have run at all - is this correct?

The reason is, in do-while the loop condition is checked only *after* the loop body is executed. I.e. it will always run at least once.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without the complete code, but it may be that you just need to invert the condition:

```
}while(!(Anfallare.armees == 0 || Forsvarare.armees == 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You condition says `... as long as one of them is 0`. What you'll want is this:

```
while(Anfallare.armees > 0 || Forsvarare.armees > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason is simple

while loops when the expression is true.

so what you want is

```
while(Anfallare.armees != 0 || Forsvarare.armees != 0);
```

but even better I would suggest

```
while(Anfallare.armees > 0 || Forsvarare.armees > 0);
```

this would allow you to be sure that your armee count never gets negative ^^

Jason